# XSLT: Extract the latest DateTime of known predecessors within two xsl:for-each loops

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given is the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <description>
        <program version="2.2.0" type="plain">
            <job id="MyJobID">
                <step id="start_of_job">
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:44.920+0200</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:45.100+0200</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_1">
                    <param name="predlist">start_of_job</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.454+0200</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.473+0200</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_2">
                    <param name="predlist">start_of_job</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:48.643+0200</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:48.675+0200</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_3">
                    <param name="predlist">step_1</param>
                    <param name="rc">0</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.442+0200</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.554+0200</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_4">
                    <param name="predlist">step_1 step_3</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:54.258+0200</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:55:49.958+0200</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_5">
                    <param name="predlist">step_1 step_2 step_4</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:55:54.550+0200</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:55:58.105+0200</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="end_of_job">
                    <param name="predlist">start_of_job step_1 step_2 step_3 step_4 step_5</param>
                    <param name="state">3</param>
                </step>
            </job>
        </program>
    </description>
    <content />
</root>
```

The objective is to obtain the **end_time** of the known predecessor steps in **predlist**, to calculate the time between the actual step **start_time** and the predecessor step **end_time** which is the latest one of the given predecessors. E.g. for Step_5 this would be the end_time of Step_4 in this case. But this won't be like this every time & the number of steps is variable. The steps are processed parallel that is why sorting the nodes by end_time won't do it in this case. But maybe I'm wrong.

I'm not very experienced with XSLT. Here is what I figured out so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Add new element -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/description/program/job/step">
            <xsl:if test="param[@name='state']=10">

                <!-- Retrieve predecessor list -->
                <xsl:variable name="predList" select="tokenize(param[@name='predlist'], ' ')"/>

                <!-- Check which predecessor finished last -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$predList">
                    <xsl:variable name="predecessor" select="."/>
                    <!-- Obtain end_time of predecessor and store it in a xsl:variable e.g. $received__predecessor_end_time somehow -->
                </xsl:for-each>

                <!-- Process ouput XML -->
                <program>
                    <xsl:attribute name="stepID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="waitTime">
                        <!-- Calculate wait time in seconds -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="duration_in_s">
                            <xsl:with-param name="dateTimeBegin" select="substring(param[@name='begin_time'],1,23)"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="dateTimeEnd" select="substring($received__predecessor_end_time,1,23)"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </program>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template: Calculate wait time in seconds -->
    <xsl:template name="duration_in_s">
        <xsl:param name="dateTimeBegin"/>
        <xsl:param name="dateTimeEnd"/>

        <xsl:variable name="DURATION"><xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime($dateTimeBegin)-xs:dateTime($dateTimeEnd)" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="((hours-from-duration($DURATION)*3600)+(minutes-from-duration($DURATION)*60)+seconds-from-duration($DURATION))" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is the scope within xsl:for-each $predList loop. Within this loop I cannot access any node to obtain its end_time. I guess my approach is wrong here.

How can I get the end_time value of the $predList predecessors & in addition to that figure out which of them is the latest one?

Note that this could be multiple DateTime values, which need to be compared with each other. XSLT 2.0 can be used here.

Comment: I know you've put some decent explanation in here, but could you provide a small sample of what you want your output to look like? I am guessing you might be better off using an extra template or two for this, but I would like to see your expected results first.

Comment: The output produced by Daniel answer is quite what I want.
See the answer & my comment on it for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the end_time value of the $predList predecessors & in addition to that figure out which of them is the latest one?

This should be pretty easy. Just get the corresponding `step`'s by tokenizing the current `predlist` and comparing it to the `id` attributes. Then use `max()` to get the latest `end_time`.

See the variable "predecessorEndTime" in my example below...

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <description>
        <program version="2.2.0" type="plain">
            <job id="MyJobID">
                <step id="start_of_job">
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:44.920+02:00</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:45.100+02:00</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_1">
                    <param name="predlist">start_of_job</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.454+02:00</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.473+02:00</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_2">
                    <param name="predlist">start_of_job</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:48.643+02:00</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:48.675+02:00</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_3">
                    <param name="predlist">step_1</param>
                    <param name="rc">0</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.442+02:00</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:54:49.554+02:00</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_4">
                    <param name="predlist">step_1 step_3</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:54:54.258+02:00</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:55:49.958+02:00</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="step_5">
                    <param name="predlist">step_1 step_2 step_4</param>
                    <param name="begin_time">2014-09-29T16:55:54.550+02:00</param>
                    <param name="end_time">2014-09-29T16:55:58.105+02:00</param>
                    <param name="state">10</param>
                </step>
                <step id="end_of_job">
                    <param name="predlist">start_of_job step_1 step_2 step_3 step_4 step_5</param>
                    <param name="state">3</param>
                </step>
            </job>
        </program>
    </description>
    <content />
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (Lots of `xsl:variable`'s to try to make it easier to see what's going on.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <results>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="step">
        <xsl:variable name="predecessors" 
            select="tokenize(param[@name='predlist'],'\s')"
            as="item()*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="predecessorEndTime" 
            select="max(../step[@id=$predecessors]/xs:dateTime(param[@name='end_time']))"
            as="xs:dateTime?"/>
        <xsl:variable name="duration" 
            select="xs:dateTime(param[@name='begin_time']) - $predecessorEndTime"
            as="xs:duration?"/>
        <xsl:variable name="waitTime" 
            select="((hours-from-duration($duration)*3600)+
            (minutes-from-duration($duration)*60)+
            seconds-from-duration($duration))"
            as="xs:double?"/>
        <program stepID="{@id}" 
            waitTime="{if ($waitTime) then $waitTime else 0}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<results>
   <program stepID="start_of_job" waitTime="0"/>
   <program stepID="step_1" waitTime="4.354"/>
   <program stepID="step_2" waitTime="3.543"/>
   <program stepID="step_3" waitTime="-0.031"/>
   <program stepID="step_4" waitTime="4.704"/>
   <program stepID="step_5" waitTime="4.592"/>
   <program stepID="end_of_job" waitTime="0"/>
</results>
```

**Edit in response to comment:**

If there are other children of `job` that should not be output, you can either narrow the scope to only `step` by adding this template:

```
<xsl:template match="job">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="step"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or you could add this template to suppress all text not handled by any other processing:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

I updated my XSLT example with the latter.

Comment: To make the solution even clearer, you could add "as" attributes to the xsl:variable declarations to show what kind of value they hold.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. This is extreme close to what I want & is very helpful.
The real life scenario has additional param tags before & after the step tags but inside the job tag. E.g. like let's say `<param name="title">Jobtitle</param> <step></step> <param name="host">192.168.2.1</param>`. Sorry, I did not have this in my mind when asking my question. With your solution these tags are processed into the output xml, too. But I just want the stepID & waitTime in it. How can this be achieved?

Comment: @user4475289 - Please see my edit. I've added 2 ways you can suppress those other `param` elements.

Comment: @DanielHaley - Thank you I use option 2 & it does what you told me.
Hope this XSLT topic won't seem like magic to me in near future any more.

Comment: @SirIO - I'm glad I could help. If you have any questions on how any of my answer works, please let me know.